# How to match the background of two buttons

Tags: java, android, button, background

Hi I'm new to programming, I know there is probably some easy answer to this but cant quite get there.

So basically I want to know if the background image for two buttons match and if they do disable them (or some other function). Heres my code, for the moment I am focusing on Button1 and Button2.

Look at the end method, I know if wont work but thats what im trying to do. Thanks.

```
package com.example.pairsgame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);}


    public final static int Button_Count = 12;

    private Button[] Buttons = new Button[Button_Count];
    {

        Buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        Buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        Buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button3);
        Buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button4);
        Buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button5);
        Buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button6);
        Buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button7);
        Buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button8);
        Buttons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button9);
        Buttons[9] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button10);
        Buttons[10] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button11);
        Buttons[11] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button12);

        Buttons[0].setOnClickListener(this);
        Buttons[1].setOnClickListener(this);
        Buttons[2].setOnClickListener(this);
        Buttons[3].setOnClickListener(this);
        Buttons[4].setOnClickListener(this);
        Buttons[5].setOnClickListener(this);
        Buttons[6].setOnClickListener(this);
        Buttons[7].setOnClickListener(this);
        Buttons[8].setOnClickListener(this);
        Buttons[9].setOnClickListener(this);
        Buttons[10].setOnClickListener(this);
        Buttons[11].setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public static int Background_Total = 8;

    public final static int[] Backgrounds = { R.drawable.ic_launcher };

    public final static int[] Game_Board = {

    0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5 };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        for (final int but = 0; but < Button_Count; but++) {
            if (v == Buttons[but]) {
                new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        Buttons[but].setBackgroundResource(Backgrounds[Game_Board[but]]);
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        Buttons[but].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
                    }
                }.start();
                if (Game_Board[0] == Game_Board[2])
                    Buttons[0].setEnabled(false);
                Buttons[2].setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: why do you need to know if background matches?

Comment: From a glance, it looks like it should work. An easy way to tell is to run it and see what happens

Comment: I am creating a pairs game, so i need to know if the BG images are the same.

Comment: Just a side note...you can clean this code up a lot by declaring the `onClick` in xml and using a `switch` on the `id` of the `View` to set the `background` and only call `new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {` once

Comment: Would that go into main.xml or would i create a new xml file?

Comment: Wherever your `Buttons` are. See [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732307/how-to-tell-which-button-was-clicked-in-onclick/15732374#15732374)

Comment: so then where would i apply the switch

Answer (score 2):

You usually want to separate your data from their representation. This has many obvious benefits, one of which will be easy testing of data without having to concern yourself with the visual representation of that data.

First things first, you will want to store your buttons in an array, as follows:

```
public final static int BUTTON_COUNT = 12; 

private Button[] buttons = new Button[BUTTON_COUNT];

Button[0] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button1 );           // Button 1
Button[1] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button2 );           // Button 2
Button[2] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button3 );           // Button 3
Button[3] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button4 );           // Button 4
Button[4] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button5 );           // Button 5
Button[5] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button6 );           // Button 6
Button[6] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button7 );           // Button 7
Button[7] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button8 );           // Button 8
Button[8] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button9 );           // Button 9
Button[9] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button10 );          // Button 10
Button[10] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button11 );         // Button 11
Button[11] = (Button)findViewById( R.id.Button12 );         // Button 12
```

This will greatly enhance the way you are able to use them, as you will see in onClick().

Next you need to define how many unique backgrounds you want, as well as the image that will represent each of them:

```
public final static int BACKGROUND_TOTAL = 8;

public final static int[] BACKGROUNDS = {
   R.drawable.ic_launcher,                           // Image 0
   R.drawable.ic_launcher2,                          // Image 1
   R.drawable.ic_launcher3,                          // Image 2
   R.drawable.ic_launcher4,                          // Image 3
   R.drawable.ic_launcher5,                          // Image 4
   R.drawable.ic_launcher6,                          // Image 5
   R.drawable.ic_launcher7,                          // Image 6
   R.drawable.ic_launcher8                           // Image 7
};
```

You also need to define what your "game board" will look like. What this will do is "associate" an image with each of your buttons. This can be done in a million different ways, but as an example let's use a fixed array. Note that each of these entries will match one of your buttons:

```
 public final static int[] GAME_BOARD = {
    0,                                         // Button 1
    0,                                         // Button 2
    1,                                         // Button 3
    1,                                         // Button 4        
    2,                                         // Button 5
    2,                                         // Button 6        
    3,                                         // Button 7
    3,                                         // Button 8        
    4,                                         // Button 9
    4,                                         // Button 10       
    5,                                         // Button 11
    5,                                         // Button 12       
 };
```

Each value here is an "index" in the BACKGROUNDS array. So all values must be between 0 and (BACKGROUND_TOTAL-1). Note that I just added sequential pairs, but obviously for a real game you will want to generate random values here. In the above example, button 3 will use image 1 and button 9 will use image 4, and so on.

With all of this information in place, this is what your onClick would look like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {    

   if ( v == buttons[0] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[0].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[0]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[0].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[1] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[1].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[1]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[1].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[2] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[2].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[2]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[2].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[3] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[3].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[0]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[3].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[4] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[4].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[4]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[4].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[5] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[5].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[5]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[5].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[6] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[6].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[6]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[6].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[7] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[7].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[7]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[7].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[8] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[8].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[8]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[8].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[9] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[9].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[9]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[9].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[10] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[10].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[10]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[10].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[11] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[11].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[11]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[11].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
   if ( v == buttons[12] )  {
      new CountDownTimer(1000, 500) {
         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             buttons[12].setBackgroundResource( BACKGROUNDS[GAME_BOARD[12]] );
         }

         public void onFinish() {
             buttons[12].setBackgroundResource( android.R.drawable.btn_default );
         }
      }.start();       
   }
}
```

And finally, instead of matching images you could simply use the following to test if two
buttons have the same background:

```
if ( GAME_BOARD[button1] == GAME_BOARD[button2] )
   // disable both buttons
```

In this case button1 and button2 should be the index values of the buttons in their arrays.

While this is a rough example, it should get you on the path to thinking about the problem in a different, more appropriate way. Good luck to you!

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the reply and the explanations, this is the logic I was trying to accomplish. But I seem to be having a problem with the "but" variable. The "but++" wants me to remove the final modifier but if i remove it the other instances of "but" want it back? Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry about that, there was a missing brace in the onClick method. I have fixed it, so try it now.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code (see above) but still getting the error, do you mind taking a look at it. Thanks for your help, just a bit stumped at the moment.

Comment: First you don't need to make the int final in the for loop, just use: for (int but = 0). Second, your comparison statement should have braces {} around the two button setEnabled statements, otherwise only the second statement will ALWAYS execute. Lastly, you will need to either add more entries to the Backgrounds array, or you should use a value of 0 for ALL entries in the Game_Board array. Also note that because you are comparing Game_Board[0] to Game_Board[2] the test will ALWAYS fail because those two have different constant values.

Comment: If the int isnt final I get the cannot refer to a non-final variable but inside an inner class defined in a different method. If the int is final i get the final local variable but cannot be assigned because it must be blank and not using compound. So i think its saying i need to declare the but variable locally but it doesnt seem to like that.

Comment: Of course, my mistake. This won't work in the onClick unless you can pass the value of 'but' as a parameter to your inner class. You could sublass the CountDownTimer to allow this, but it might be overkill for what your are trying to achieve. Instead, just skip the looping in onClick and go back to setting it up on a per button basis, using constant integers to refer to the buttons instead - i have changed my code above to show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic probably shouldn't rely on the background images of the buttons, which are UI elements, they should be separated from the logic of your game (separation of concern).

What I would do is keep somewhere in memory (in `Application` maybe?) a structure that "knows" which image is set as the background of each button, and use that to compare and drive the disabling of the linked buttons: instead of trying to compare two UI elements, you could have a normal class with methods that you write to compare the two image objects (from some sort of ID maybe?), and then set the buttons accordingly.

Among other benefits (separation of concerns, clearer design, etc.), that would make your logic testable.

Comment: Yeah thats sort of what im asking/trying to do. A structure that knows which image is set as Bg