# How can I set the @string reference with java

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I have 8 buttons and each button should take you to the same activity but the title of the activity will change depending on which button you press.

The idea behind this is that I have 8 Movie screens and each button corresponds to a screen (1 through 8). so inside the onclick method i will use the proper query for that screen and set the title to that specific screen number. There are better ways to do this im sure like with a drop down list but i just want to know for what i have already.

Is there a way to set the title of the page with a @string reference or do i need to hard code the title in the button's onclick method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out the way i wanted to do it. I'm willing to change it if anyone has any other ideas. im new to android programming so i may not understand it. but this was my solution.

```
    public void theaterOneButtonOnClick(View v) {

    String title = ("" + R.string.theater_number1);
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TheaterActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("title", title);

    startActivity(i);

}

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.theater_activity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String sTitle = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    TextView msgTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    int title = Integer.parseInt(sTitle);
    msgTextView.setText(title);


}
```

}

Comment: It looks like you're setting the same title no matter which button is clicked

Comment: @codeMagic oh i see what you are saying. you are assumming that i am using the same listener for all 8 buttons. i didn't think of that. in that case i would need to get the button text like you were suggesting. im a beginner-ish.

Comment: Yes, since they all do the same thing but change a variable this would make sense

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732307/how-to-tell-which-button-was-clicked-in-onclick/15732374#15732374) to use on listener. It will make your code more efficient and readable. I guess I didn't understand exactly how you knew which string you wanted. I assumed it was the `Button` text. But that answer should help you consolidate your code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to access string resources from java code instead of xml. You can do that by using the generated R class.

E.g. `R.string.my_title`. This will give you a resource id for that particular entry. If you want to get the string value of it, you call `Context.getString(R.string.my_title)`.

More information on that can be found in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromCode

Comment: Cool that seems pretty easy and straight forward.

Comment: Yes but how will you know which title was passed?

Comment: Ah, I did not completely understand the question at first. wyatt, see codeMagic's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the text with the click

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    String title = ((Button).getText();
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NextActivitiy.class);
    i.putExtra("title", title);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

This is assuming that the `String resource` you are referring to is the text of the `Button`. You will have to send the title one way or another so this should work.

Then in your next `Activity` use something like

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String title = intent.getStringExtra("title");
```

Comment: can i just use the title String to set the preferences of the Label that is my title?

    String titleString = getString(R.string.theater_number1);

but i don't know how to set the preferences with methods from inside the class.

Comment: Now I think I am confused. You will have different titles depending on which `Button` is pressed, correct? And the title for the next `Activity` is the text of the `Button` pressed? That is how I'm seeing your question

Comment: yes. maybe we mean different things when i say title. The activity im calling has a textview at the top of the screen and i'd like to set that textview to "theater 1" through 8. i think what you have given me is good i just don't know how to access that specific textview and set the text.

Comment: What is the text on your `Buttons`? Is that what you want for your title on the next `Activity`? Or how do you decide what the title will be?

Comment: i answered my own question. What do you think about the solution?

Comment: Where do you get the `title` value from? Maybe I don't understand but I would assume that it is the text on your `Button`. It's not the same for each `Button` clicked, right? So there has to be something that decides what it is

Comment: here the button and the title happen to have the same text so i could have done it your way but instead i called a reference from R.string.

the deciding factor is in the onClick i posted the answer, did you see it?

Comment: I did I just don't see how you determine which string to use for the title

Comment: The value of the string has a pointer so i just took the value of that pointer and made it into a string number. This happens in the onClick method this is where i get the specific title i want e.g. Theater 1, Theater 2, etc... i then pass that string to my activity that im starting. Parse that integer string into an integer and pass that integer to the setText method of my TextView.