# Having multiple buttons, serving different layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on a quick mockup for an app I'm in the making of, and the idea is pretty simple so far.

I have a total of 6 buttons, and each button is sort of like a link to another activity or another layout.

Programmatically it would serve me best to have each button serve a different xml-layout depending on what button is clicked, right? However, I have trouble wrapping my mind around how the android environment works.

How could this be implemented the best way? I already know how to catch a clicked button, I'm thinking of having a switch statement which picks that up, and sending the user to an activity which then again shows the appropriate information.

I do not need to have a database with the information in yet, as only two buttons have to actually be working so far.

Thanks in advance for any answers!

Edit:

Elaboration and visualization:

This is an example of one list I want to pull up when a button is pressed.

```
<ul>
    <li>This is the first line</li>
    <ul>
        <li>this is nested text (second line)</li>
        <li>Another second level nest</li>
        <ul>
            <li>Third level nest (third line)</li>
        </ul>
     </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: There isn't much of a question here. You need to start on your code and ask a more specific question. However, it sounds like you are on the right track. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15732307/how-to-tell-which-button-was-clicked-in-onclick/15732374#15732374) on using the same function for multiple `Button`s. Then change the `Activity` in the `Intent` that you start depending on which was clicked.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16801306/how-to-do-multiple-intents/16801416#16801416) may also give you a different idea of how to handle the `Intent`

Comment: Yes, but the troubles I have are in regards to where I need to store the information (a basic string isn't enough, as it's sort of a <ul><li> nested sort of deal). Also, how I pull up this information based on the button clicked.

Comment: You haven't said *what* the problem is. You need to give more information in your post if you want adequate help.

Comment: My problem is as follows, I'll write it again and again if it's necessary.

I do not know where to store multiple lines of information, and I do not know how to pull this up in a single activity based on a button click, or an intent or whatever.

Comment: You have said nothing about the type, amount, or anything else of the data/information that you want to display

Comment: The type of information is just lists. There should be two/three different lists that should be pulled up according to button pressed. Each list is nested with a little more information, like in a standard html list, [visualized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171064/having-multiple-buttons-serving-different-layout) in OP.

Comment: So, would this be on one dialog box? Like Line 1, Line 2, and Line 3 would all be right below eachother?

Comment: Correct, but in a nested/tabbed fashion, so the top is leftmost positioned, while the next has some padding and the next has the parents padding + extra padding (if you catch my drift, it's 3am here and I have a few more hours until turn in, assignment from my boss, which I got too little time to work on)

Answer (score 0):

Android training might be a good place to start: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: [I elaborated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171064/having-multiple-buttons-serving-different-layout#comment28362217_19171064) a little on what I need. The training isn't sufficient for me, I'm afraid.