# Adding content to a ScrollView dynamically

Tags: android

I have the following layout in my activity

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/topHeading"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewlinearlayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <!--
             Content will be dynamically added to this portion.
            -->
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

In my activity code i inflate a view and add to the above layout

```
    LinearLayout scrollViewLinearLayout=(LinearLayout)root.findViewById(R.id.scrollViewlinearlayout);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.lesson_row,null,false);
            Button b1=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
            b1.setOnClickListener(this);
            scrollViewLinearLayout.addView(view);
    }
```

Now this works fine. I have 10 layouts in my scrollview layout.  Now the `R.layout.lesson_row` contains buttons that i want to click on. I can easily add a click listener to the button but which button of the 10 layouts was clicked ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15732374/1380752

Comment: or just use ListView instead ....

Comment: Its a Horizontal Layout.

Comment: How about new RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager with orientation: HORIZONTAL

Answer (score 0):

Associate an ID or a tag with the `Button` instances that you are creating, so that you can tell them apart.

Or, put the `Button` instances in a `HashMap<Button, ThingTiedToButtonGoesHere>`, or other Java data structure, so you can do a lookup at runtime.